# Are there any downsides to using "using" for all non-primitive objects?

Tags: c#, coding-style, using

I'm sure there are answers out there ... but googling on "C# using" is a bit more complicated than you may expect.

At any rate ... just really started learning about this handy technique the other day and it seems like I would be foolish to not use it for any non-primitive objects I have in my code.

Is that a fairly accurate statement or are there some downsides (outside of the slightly more cluttered code) to using "using" for almost everything?

Comment: Can you give an example how you are using "using"?

Comment: `using` only works for objects which implement `IDisposable`. Try doing a search for `when to use IDisposable` and you'll find your answer.

Comment: C#'s `using` statement only works with classes that implement `IDisposable`. All it does is call the object's `Dispose()` implementation at the end of the block.

Comment: More specifically, it wraps the code in a `try/finally` block, with `Dispose` being called in the `finally`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can only use a `using` statement on types that implement `IDisposable`. For types that do implement `IDisposable`, the only real downside I have seen is due to the fact that `using` calls the type's `Dispose()` method implicitly, so if an exception is thrown in that call, it is sometimes difficult to catch.

Otherwise, I would recommend `using` for types that implement `IDisposable` instead of utilizing try-catch-finally as it makes code more compact and clean.

**Edit:** found a good [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx) explaining this and other pitfalls.

Comment: The fact that it won't compile at all on types it's not applicable might be considered a downside too...

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what you mean - if you mean using statements such as:

```
using (SomeType x = new SomeType())
{
}
```

Then that's *only* applicable to `IDisposable` implementations.

If you mean using *directives* like this:

```
using System.IO;
```

then yes, I usually have a directive for every namespace containing a type I wish to use within a particular source file.